# How to see what's going on during hibernation instead of staring at a black screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, hibernate, desktop-computer

> I put the pc to hibernation more than one hour ago. Screen is black,
>   no signal. Mouse and keyboard are not doing anything. Fans are
>   spinning a lot. I issued the command using Team viewer. The remote
>   control  session has been automatically disconnected, indicating that 
>   the hibernation procedure has started.
>
> What should I do? There may be some important documents open.

After 8 hours of asking this question I had to reboot. Is there a way to make windows more verbose during hibernation? I would like to see what operations are being done and where it gets stuck. Something like Linux system console.

Comment: It would help to know if this PC had ever hibernated properly before.  In any case, worst-case is to hold down the power button 10 seconds then tell it to do a normal boot.  All you are likely to lose is whatever was unsaved in your programs.  My motto is that whenever I have done enough work that I don't want to have to do it again then it is time to save.

Comment: I usually hibernate instead of shutting down so this is abnormal (BTW after 8 hours it is still stuck. I am resetting.)

Comment: OK.  Yikes.  Maybe a glitch with the actual hiberfile.  I don't know whether you can delete it and start over, but I'd bet someone here will have some guidance to help.  Yes, after 8 hours it sounds like a hard shutoff and restart is going to be called for.  :-(

Comment: This is not possible. the gpu driver is suspended very early in hibernation process.

Answer (score 2):

Does your computer have a drive activity indicator? If it does, is it blinking? If the indicator is off, your computer has likely either finished writing the contents of your ram to the Windows hiberfile or frozen in the process.

If the computer is still actively accessing the drive, try issuing the 3-finger salute: CTRL+ALT+DEL. Some Windows 10 users at my university have had a similar problem and using CTRL+ALT+DEL snapped the computers out of it.

If worst comes to worst, though, it may be completely frozen and will require a forced reboot to escape.

Comment: Good answer.  I see this happen a lot on Hibernate with all versions of Windows, depending on the machine.  It would help if we knew if this PC had ever hibernated properly before.

Comment: No blinking. I should have specified that I tried ctrl alt del before declaring the mouse and keyboard unresponsive. I am forcing a reboot now. It's been 8 hours of this . I usually hibernate this pc flawlessly.

Comment: Yep.  It is locked up tight.  Power is really the only option.